# passing the selected object from list of objects that each one has its own button

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I’m working on a web-app that displays list of objects, each object has its own modal when clicked inside the modal there are two dropdown menus and a button that is supposed to call a method add in a bean, to perform an action and add the selected object while taking three values, selected object, selected two items from the two drop downs and spinner’s value.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{ViewTeacher.teacherList}" var="teacher"
varStatus="status">


<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="name">
<p>#{teacher.name}</p>

</h:panelGroup>
<br />
<br />
<a onclick="viewModal(#{status.index})" class="btn btn-success">view</a>

<h:panelGroup id="modal" layout="block" class="modal"
style="max-width: 44em;" tabindex="1">
<h:panelGroup class="modal-content" layout="block">
<span class="close" onclick="modClose()">&times;</span>

<h:outputText styleClass="description" value="#{teacher.name}" />
<br />
<br />

<br />
students


<h:selectOneMenu value="ok" class="form-control">

<f:selectItems value="#{teacher.students}" var="s"
itemValue="#{s.id}" itemLabel="#{s.name}" />



</h:selectOneMenu>


classes

<h:selectOneMenu value="ok" class="form-control">
<f:selectItems value="#{teacher.classes}" var="c"
itemValue="#{c.id}" itemLabel="#{c.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<br />

<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="form-group">


<p:spinner min="1" max="10" />

</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandButton id="submitButton" styleClass="btn btn-success" value="ADD">
<!—-this is the button that is supposed to take the values



</h:commandButton>

<a onclick="modClose()" class="btn btn-success">CANCEL</a>

</h:panelGroup>


</h:panelGroup>


</ui:repeat>
```

I tried :

```
<f:param name="name1" value="China" />
```

But the fact that param’s name will get repeated, will make it the same all the time and might be set to the latest object retrieved,

Any recommendation?

UPDATE:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-success" process="@this"
    onclick="viewModal(#{status.index});">
    <h:outputText value="ADD" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener
        value="#{teacher.id}" target="#{ViewTeacher.selectedTeacher}" /> 

        </p:commandLink>
```

Made this change to pass the teacher's id but it's still null in the bean

Comment: You are not using `update="modal"` on the `p:commandLink`. That is why values in the pop-up are not getting updated.

Comment: I think, you were using the `selectedTeacher` object wrong. You have to use `students` and `classes` from that (`selectedTeacher`) object on modal and additional properties from the bean.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having a separate modal for each object isn't a good idea. You can achieve (what you are trying) by:

1). Adding a property (with its getter and setter) in bean for selected object.

2). Place single modal (`<p:dialog` with `id="modal"` and `widgetVar="modal"` attributes) outside `ui:repeat` to display data from selected object.

3). Set selected object on clicking view link, update and display modal, using:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-success" process="@this" update="modal"
    onclick="PF('modal').show();">
    <h:outputText value="View" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        value="#{teacher}" target="#{ViewTeacher.selectedTeacher}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Here, `f:setPropertyActionListener` will be setting your selected modal in bean and thus it will become available in your action listener.

**Update: Change the code as following:**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{ViewTeacher.teacherList}" var="teacher" varStatus="status">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="name">
        <p>#{teacher.name}</p>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-success" process="@this" update="modal"
        oncomplete="PF('modal').show();">
        <h:outputText value="view" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener
            value="#{teacher}" target="#{ViewTeacher.selectedTeacher}" />
    </p:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>

<p:dialog id="modal" widgetVar="modal" header="Edit Teacher" modal="true"
    showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true"
    styleClass="teachers-dialog">

    <h:outputText styleClass="description" value="#{ViewTeacher.selectedTeacher.name}" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    students
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ViewTeacher.selectedStudentId}" class="form-control">
        <f:selectItems value="#{ViewTeacher.selectedTeacher.students}"
            var="s" itemValue="#{s.id}" itemLabel="#{s.name}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    classes
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ViewTeacher.selectedClassId}" class="form-control">
        <f:selectItems value="#{ViewTeacher.selectedTeacher.classes}"
            var="c" itemValue="#{c.id}" itemLabel="#{c.name}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <br />

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="form-group">
        <p:spinner value="#{ViewTeacher.spinnerValue}" min="1" max="10" />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:commandButton id="submitButton" styleClass="btn btn-success" value="ADD">
    </h:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

Where `selectedTeacher`, `selectedStudentId`, `selectedClassId`, `spinnerValue` are properties from your `ViewTeacher` bean.

Comment: thank you, is it ok to have the modal outside the repeat even if the information will be displayed are different in each modal?

Comment: also I wanted to ask, in the action listener i wanted to send teacher, selected class, and selected student(these two were selected from the modal) is this possible? and is the commandlink you just poster inside the repeat?

Comment: For 1st Comment: Yes, because the selected object is updated each time view link is clicked.

Comment: For 2nd Comment: You need to place additional properties for the selected class and student in your bean. And yes, `commandLink` is same as your view link and will be placed in the repeat.

Comment: added the action listener but it's not getting updated, anything special the declaration of the selectedteacher needs? or annotation that it's for the action listener??

Comment: do i have to make it like :  public void changeteacher (ValueChangeEvent event) {
             selectedteacher = evet.getNewValue().toString();
     }??

Comment: What is your bean property for selected teacher? Is it `selectedTeacher` as per my code, or `selectedteacher`?

Comment: In your modal, you need to use that property for the bean.

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: the product is just null, that's what i mean.. not updated even though the button is clicked

Comment: It should be updated on view link click and should be available when you are clicking update. Can you please update your modified code?

Comment: Updated, even i tried value=“6” but 6 has never gone to the bean

Comment: I don't see any changes in your updated code, suggested by me.

Comment: You can, but need to update the modal as well on clicking the command button / link.

Comment: I think eeverytime my bean gets called lije : ViewTeacher.something, it gets initialised and passes through the instructor, It seems it will work will application scoped beanm but later I will have a login page and logged in user, should work in the mean time on application scoped bean then after having the login page.. etc change it to a session bean?

Comment: It should work with the request scoped bean as well.

Comment: It's not, is there any annotation i should add?